# routing rules and orders in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, service-provider

I am making a modulized app with laravel 5.0 and for this , I created a serviceProvider that's called ModuleServiceProvider , and for including routes of each module , in Boot function of ModuleServiceProvider , I wrote `include base_app()."/app/Modules/$ModuleName/routes.php";`. Now , my question is this: when I enter the module page address in browser it has returned errors such as `NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 259: Controller method not found.` . I know that it is caused by / route in Http/routes.php 
How can I fixed it ?

sorry for weak English.

Comment: can you show the relevant code in your `Controller.php` and `routes.php` files?

Comment: I solved it by change my routing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when you define routes on /* subaddress , for correct working in the / route (in controller method such as `Route::Controller('/','IndexController')`) , it should enter after all routes. on the other hand when you include some routes from service Providers or another files , the included routes would be processed after Http/Routes. for solving this problem we should change our routing writing for `Root (/)` route and rewrite it to a regular `route::get` method.

sorry for weak English.
Thanks all